# How can I get pixel values of a texture in Starling?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe, starling-framework

To test some image-loading code I wrote in AS3 using the traditional display hierarchy, I would ensure that pixel colors were the right values.

Now I've started to port that code over to Starling, I've noticed that `Texture`s don't have an easy way to get pixel values. This is unfortunate, because it means I'd have to toss a lot of good tests.

Is there any possible way I could do this? Like, could I convert a `Texture` to `BitmapData` somehow? Or do you guys have any other suggestions for how to test to ensure that I've properly loaded an image?

Comment: still doesn't seem possible:  http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/bitmapdata-from-texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, this is possible in a limited subset of cases (but the ones that I needed!). The following code is Haxe, but hopefully anyone coming from an AS3 background should be able to translate it with minimal difficulty.

```
public function getPixel(x:Int, y:Int, sprite: Starling.display.Sprite) : UInt {
    var sw: Int = stage.stageWidth;
    var sh: Int = stage.stageHeight;

    var support:RenderSupport = new RenderSupport();
    RenderSupport.clear(flash.Lib.current.stage.color, 1.0);
    support.setOrthographicProjection(0, 0, sw, sh);
    Fathom.starling.stage.render(support, 1.0);
    support.finishQuadBatch();

    var result:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sw, sh, true);
    Starling.context.drawToBitmapData(result);

    return result.getPixel(Std.int(sprite.x) + x, Std.int(sprite.y) + y);
}
```

What this code does is render every object that's being displayed in a 3D context to the `result` BitmapData. Then, we grab a pixel from that BitmapData at the location where the sprite is.

This isn't perfect - it doesn't consider things like rotations, scales, etc. It also doesn't consider if `sprite` does not have the highest depth. However it is helpful for testing, and it might also come in handy if you need to take a screenshot of the current state of the app/game.